# How to unnest fields in json that contain map coordinates int list column in r?

Tags: r, json, tidyr, jsonlite, unnest

I have read **json .txt file** and looking to extract `geometry` & `coordinates` field from the data which is nested inside.

But having issues in **unnesting** `coordinates` data due to **<int []> list column** in it.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

India_map_data <- fromJSON(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/India_map_data.txt"))
```

Below code works fine

```
India_map_data %>% 
  .$features %>% 
  map_if(is.data.frame, list) %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
  unnest(properties, geometry)
```

```
A tibble:1,369 x 10
hc-middle-x  hc-middle-y  type1 coordinates
<dbl>         <dbl>       <chr> <list>
0.50    0.50    MultiPolygon    <list [2]>
0.50    0.50    MultiPolygon    <list [4]>
0.35    0.70    MultiPolygon    <list [3]>
0.50    0.50    Polygon <int [1 × 45 × 2]>
0.50    0.50    MultiPolygon    <list [2]>
0.50    0.50    Polygon <int [1 × 5 × 2]>
0.50    0.50    MultiPolygon    <list [8]>
0.50    0.50    MultiPolygon    <list [2]>
0.60    0.75    MultiPolygon    <list [4]>
0.62    0.82    MultiPolygon    <list [6]>
```

But when I `unnest(coordinates)` it gives error

```
India_map_data %>% 
  .$features %>% 
  map_if(is.data.frame, list) %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
  unnest(properties, geometry) %>% 
  unnest(coordinates)
```

> **Error: Can't combine `..1$coordinates`  and `..4$coordinates` <integer[,45,2]>.**

How can I fix this so that I can use this data further to plot?